# Mysql Error while droping database table

Tags: mysql

I couldn't drop a database table from mysql server , an error occurs as shown.
what was the problem please?
Great thanks 
[image: error]

Comment: What is in the error log?

Comment: When posting; it helps to show the actual code ran and the result (error with complete text) and explain what you expected to happen.

Answer (score -1):

for 500 Internal Server Error, you will first want to check any Apache and PHP error logs for your server. These logs can provide valuable context related to any code failures or other potential causes of a site failure. For information on where to find the logs for your server-
/usr/local/cpanel/logs/access_log